# integration tests and UI changes

Tags: java, jsp, testing, integration-testing, web-testing

Our web application has many integration tests. How to deal with changes to UI structure of page? All tests based on xpath with id and specific tag name (what is really bad).

Group of ids are a contract, but how web developer can easily modify pages without failing tests?

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed, XPath expressions are pretty fragile, as even small changes to the page structure can break them. I wouldn't recommend using them in tests as a way to find specific element.

Can your tests be rewritten to search for elements using only their unique IDs, and not on XPath expressions? IDs are pretty easy to preserve while modifying the page.

Alternatively - if, for some reason you need to change IDs of elements often - maybe you could add another attribute to HTML tags containing unique and unchanging 'testing ID', like this:

```
<a href="mylink.html" id="idThatWillBeChanged" test-id="myLink">My link</a>
```

Then you could locate elements using that test-id. Unfortunatelly, adding such an attribute would mean your pages stop validating as valid HTML, and some IDEs will mark that as an error.

Comment: Yes. This is the idea which I really want to go to. But after all ui changes a dev should run integration tests. Am I right?

Comment: If the tests don't take too much time, sure. Speaking from my experience, though, integration tests can take quite long (unlike unit tests). If this is the case, and you use a continous integration server like Jenkins, you could make them run there automatically after each VCS commit, while developer is busy doing other things.

Comment: Ok but the process need to be modified. I must say to devs: "watch the jenkins and be ready to fix tests."

Comment: Jenkins can be set up to send e-mails to those responsible after test failures. As for the 'be ready to fix tests' part, well, no way around it.

Comment: @socha23 BTW, instead of custom attribute you may use new `data-*` attributes from HTML5. See: http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand root of the problem is that you should reflect DOM's changes in all test cases. This [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) violation may eliminated by adding another abstraction layer with [PageObject pattern](http://www.shino.de/2011/07/26/on-the-pageobject-pattern/). In this case when element changed you will update it XPath only in one class.

See also:

- http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects
- http://blog.josephwilk.net/cucumber/page-object-pattern.html